# Mac OS X 10.6.3 update: Freezes mouse every now and then

Tags: macos, mouse, updates, freeze

Ever since I updated my early 2010 MacBook Pro 13" with the 10.6.3 update, **the mouse pointer freezes for 5 to 10 seconds**, every now and then. The keyboard is next to unresponsive when this happens.

Are there more people having the same problem? Is this a known bug?

**Is there a solution?**

Comment: There is a 10.6.3 v1.1 update available http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1017 . However, the documentation doesn't say anything about mouse problems. It may not solve your problem, but can't hurt?

Comment: @Steve Folly - That's the update that caused the mouse freezing in the first pace I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not alone in this one, I'm afraid. There's a 10 page long topic over on http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2382651&tstart=1 and lots of people (including me) have reported the same thing...

No resolution yet.